# update multiple lines of table in erlang

Tags: erlang

I want to know how can I update multiple records of table

for example  I have a table named :  **transaction**

I want to modifiy the **id** of  **transaction**

I try without success with

```
  testupdate()->
        Key =20,
        Update=#transaction{id=Key} ,
    Fun = fun() ->
                  List = mnesia:match_object(Update),
                  lists:foreach(fun(X) ->
                                        mnesia:write_object(X)
                                end, List)
          end,
    mnesia:transaction(Fun).
```

when I test I didn't find an error

```
1> model:testupdate().
{atomic,ok}
```

but the **id** of **transaction** are not changed

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983345/update-multiple-record-in-erlang).

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the `Type of Table`, and what field you are updating in the records. Unfortunately, you have not told us some details about your table. Lets say, you are updating multiple records basing on a given field.

**NOTE** that i do not recommend the use of the word `transaction` as a table name. But for purposes of learning, lets continue. Pseudo Code:

```
Get all records whose: Obj#transaction.field == Key
Then, Foreach, set: Obj#transaction.field == Key2
```

Then consider this example basing on `Query List Comprehension`

```
-include_lib("stdlib/include/qlc.hrl").

select(Q)->
    case mnesia:is_transaction() of
        false -> 
            F = fun(QH)-> qlc:e(QH) end,
            mnesia:activity(transaction,F,[Q],mnesia_frag);
        true -> qlc:e(Q)
    end.

gen_update(FilterFun,UpdateFun)->
    A = select(qlc:q([R || R <- mnesia:table(transaction),FilterFun(R) == true])),
    [UpdateFun(X) || X <- A],
    ok.

update_by_key(OldKey,NewKey)->
    FilterFun = fun(#transaction{key = OldKey}) -> true;
                    (_) -> false
                end,
    UpdateFun = fun(T) ->
                    NewT = T#transaction{key = NewKey},
                    mnesia:write(NewT),
                    ok
                end,
    gen_update(FilterFun,UpdateFun),
    ok.
```

That should do it. Look at the function: `gen_update`. I have used `funs` to create generic Objects which will filter according to any desired form, and another which will do the update. Now, you can construct any `fun` of your choice as long as it takes in a record as an argument. Note that this method may be applicable to tables of type `set`, depending on what you are doing. If you are updating by `primary key`, then, you need to make some new changes.