# update multiple record in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a table person  with this record

```
-record(person, {id, firstname, lastname, phone}).
```

I want to update the phone of all records of this table
Itry with

```
test()->
        Newphone ="216",
        Update=#person{phone=Newphone} ,
    Fun = fun() ->
                  List = mnesia:match_object(Update),
                  lists:foreach(fun(X) ->
                                        mnesia:write_object(X)
                                end, List)
          end,
    mnesia:transaction(Fun).
```

The table **person** contains

```
 12  alen     dumas        97888888
    15  franco   mocci      55522225
    13  ali      othmani    44444449
```

I want that this table became like this :

```
 12  alen     dumas      216
    15  franco   mocci      216
    13  ali      othmani    216
```

I try with :

```
test()->
    Newphone ="216",
    Update=X#person{phone=Newphone, _ = '_'}
Fun = fun() ->
              List = mnesia:match_object(Update),
              lists:foreach(fun(X) ->
                                    mnesia:write(X)
                            end, List)
      end,
mnesia:transaction(Fun).
```

but with this code I have this error :

```
Variable X is unbound
```

this is related to this line :

```
Update=X#person{phone=Newphone, _ = '_'}
```

to resolve this probleme I do :

```
test()->
    Newphone ="216",
    Update=#person{phone=Newphone, _ = '_'}
Fun = fun() ->
              List = mnesia:match_object(Update),
              lists:foreach(fun(X) ->
                                    mnesia:write(X)
                            end, List)
      end,
mnesia:transaction(Fun).
```

when I test I have this message :

```
{atomic,ok}
```

but when I consult the database I find that **the records are not changed**

**the difficulty in my code is to change all records of the table person**

so change **97888888** and **55522225** and **44444449**

this values should became **216**

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from what @legoscia has started. There are a couple of problems left with your code:

1. In the `mnesia:match_object/1` call `Update` is being used as a **pattern** so when you set the `phone` field `phone=NewPhone` in `Update` you are actually saying to `match_object` give me all the records which have a `phone` of value `"216"`. Which is not what you want.
2. You are writing back **exactly the same record** as you matched. You are not changing the record before writing it back.

A solution could be (untested):

```
test()->
    Newphone ="216",
    Match=#person{_ = '_'},                               %Will match all records
    Fun = fun() ->
              List = mnesia:match_object(Match),
              lists:foreach(fun(X) ->
                                %% Create new record with phone=NewPhone and write it back
                                Update = X#person{phone=NewPhone},
                                mnesia:write(Update)
                            end, List)
          end,
    mnesia:transaction(Fun).
```

Any fields you set in `Match` will limit which records you will match in `match_object`. For example `Match = #person{phone="123",_='_'}` will match all records which have phone `"123"`.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,  I want that the value of phone is the old value with the new value  for example if the phone is 97888888  it will became 21697888888  ,  I try in the code with :  Update = X#person{phone=phone+NewPhone},

Comment: @nabilchouaib That will not work as `+` only operates on numbers and you phone numbers are strings (which is at it should be). You need to do `Update = X#person{phone=NewPhone ++ X#person.phone}`. This will **prefix** `NewPhone` to the old phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A few things need changing here:

1. If you are going to use a record as a template for [mnesia:match_object](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#match_object-1), you should fill in the record fields that you don't care about with the atom `'_'`. There is a special syntax to do that:

   ```
   Update=#person{phone=Newphone, _ = '_'}
   ```
2. You probably don't want `Newphone` in there—the record that you pass to `match_object` should match the objects that are already in the table but should be changed, not what you want the objects to be changed to.

   Which records are you trying to change?  That will determine what you should pass to `match_object`.
3. The only thing you do in the transaction is reading records and writing them back unchanged.  Have a look at [the Records chapter of the Erlang reference manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html); you probably want something like `X#person{phone = Newphone}` to change the phone field in `X`.
4. The function `mnesia:write_object` doesn't exist; you probably meant [mnesia:write](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#write-1).

Comment: Read through points 1 and 2 of my answer again; the solution to this error is in there.

Comment: You still haven't considered points 2 and 3 in my answer. Change your code according to them, and you should see that it works better.

Comment: In this case, I actually can't.  I don't know which records you want to change, and I don't know how you want to change them.  Therefore it would be impossible for me to write code that does what you want it to do.

Comment: If you want _all_ records, you just need `mnesia:match_object(#person{_ = '_'})`, which will return the list of all records, and you can change each record as in point 3 in my answer.